# Set equality 2 sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A useful way to show that two sets have the same elements is to show that each set is a subset of the other. I am not sure I get that intuitively, so I decided to try to prove it. So let $A$ and $B$ be sets. We know $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$. That is $\forall x(x\in A \rightarrow x\in B)$ from the first one and $\forall x(x\in B \rightarrow x\in A)$ from the second. What do we do know to show $A=B$? It’s not clear for me from here, so I would be grateful if you helped me understand the proof and the statement.

Comment: See [the Cantor Schroder Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)

Comment: Note:  it's not clear what $A=B$ means here.  the result just tells you that there is a bijection between the sets, it certainly doesn't say that the sets are equal.

Comment: Isn't this the definition of set equality? Unless you're somehow using a different definition?

Comment: What you are trying to prove is actually an axiom of set theory in ZFC (the most popular axiomatic system for set theory). It’s called the axiom of extensionality. You can’t prove axioms!

Comment: @lulu The question is not about cardinalities, so I don't see how Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein Theorem is relevant.

Comment: @Porky Strictly speaking, it's not the axiom. A small logical argument is necessary to see that the two implications imply a single equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

The Axiom of Extensionality says (from Jech's **Set Theory**, 2nd Edition):
$$\forall u(u\in X\leftrightarrow u\in Y)\rightarrow X=Y.$$
Or informally:

> If $X$ and $Y$ have the same elements, then $X=Y$.

We *define* "is a subset of" by:
$$\forall u(u\in X\to y\in Y)\iff X\subseteq Y.$$
So, "proving that two sets are equal by proving that each is a subset of the other" amounts to noticing that
$$\forall u(u\in X\leftrightarrow u\in Y)\equiv \Bigl(\forall u(u\in X\to u\in Y)\Bigr)\wedge \Bigl( \forall u(u\in Y\to u\in X)\Bigr),$$
which follows from propositional logic, since $A\leftrightarrow B$ is equivalent to $(A\to B)\wedge (B\to A)$, and $\forall x(A\wedge B)$ is equivalent to $(\forall x(A))\wedge (\forall x (B))$.

So there is no "proof" involved. It's just the definition of "equality of sets", and basic propositional logic equivalences at play.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of what it means for two sets to be equal (that they have the same elements); as Porky says in the comments it's called the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality). So there's nothing to prove.

The axiom of extensionality is telling you something about what concept a set is supposed to capture - a set is supposed to be the collection of all of its elements, and that naturally leads to this notion of equality.